# Error en programa para multiplicar dos valores introducidos por el usuario y sumar cada carácter

Tags: c++, string, integer

resulta que tengo que elaborar un programa dónde el usuario introduzca dos valores enteros y a través de una función tipo string acabar devolviendo la suma de cada dígito de la multiplicación de los enteros presentada como cadena. Sin embargo me da diversos errores como:     The simplification of the multiplication between 391 and 1 is 0 -----> Habría de dar "13" ya que 391 * 1 = 391 ---> 3+9+1 = 13.
Adjunto el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string simplifyNumber(int a, int b);
string simplifyNumber(int a, int b){
  int multiplication = 0;
  int total = 0;
  multiplication = a * b;
  string string_total = to_string(multiplication);
  if (string_total.length() > 1){
    for(int i; i < string_total.length(); i++){
      total += (string_total[i] - '0');
                                              }
                                }
  return to_string(total);
                                              }
int main(){
  int a, b;
  cin >> a >> b;
  string total = simplifyNumber(a, b);
  cout << "The simplification of the multiplication between " << a << " and " << b << " is " << total;
  return 0;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Me podrías decir cual es el valor inicial de `i`?

```
for(int i; i < string_total.length(); i++){
  total += (string_total[i] - '0');
```

Si te fijas, **no está inicializada**, luego su valor inicial es aleatorio y para nada predecible.

Acostumbra a inicializar las variables para evitar sustos:

```
for(int i=0; i < string_total.length(); i++){
//      ^^^
```

En cualquier caso, nota que el `if` que precede a este bucle es prescindible. El bucle debería recorrer la cadena al completo, luego si la misma está vacía no habrá iteraciones:

```
// if (string_total.length() > 1){
for(int i; i < string_total.length(); i++){
  total += (string_total[i] - '0');
```

También te sugiero tabular correctamente el código. Al igual que tu madre te obliga a tener tu habitación recogida y de la misma manera que en los exámenes intentas poner las ideas de forma ordenada, el código no es una excepción. Código bien tabulado = código más legible = más sencillo de entender:

```
for(int i; i < string_total.length(); i++){
  total += (string_total[i] - '0');
} // Las llaves donde corresponden
```

Aunque claro, te podrías haber ahorrado las conversiones a `string` de una forma muy sencilla: dividiendo entre 10:

```
multiplication = a * b;
while( multiplicacion != 0 )
{
  total += multiplicacion % 10;
  multiplicacion /= 10;
}
```

Por otro lado, fíjate que las declaraciones de las funciones solo son necesarias cuando no tienes disponible la implementación en el momento de usar la función. Es decir, si la función la usas en el mismo archivo pero **despues** de implementarla, no hace falta la declaración:

```
string simplifyNumber(int a, int b); // Declaración -> prescindible en este caso
string simplifyNumber(int a, int b){ // Implementación
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se escuentra en el `for` cuando haces `total += (string_total[i] - '0');` esto lo puedes solucionar declarando una variable temporal de tipo `int` en la cual vas a ir convirtiendo cada uno de los carácteres a entero y posteriormente sumarlos a `total`

```
if (string_total.length() > 1)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i; i < string_total.length(); i++)
    {
        temp = string_total[i]-'0';
        total += temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo cómo usar una variable temporal nueva ayuda a resolver el problema

Comment: Intenta ejecutar el código agregando las modificaciones que hice, por otro lado deja el código tal cual él lo tiene y solo deja la declaración de la variable ```temp``` que yo tengo y lo vuelves a ejecutar, ¿me podrías explicar qué es lo que pasa al final?

Comment: Que esa variable **no aporta absolutamente nada**. Te da lo mismo hacer `total += string_total[i]-'0'` que `total += temp`. Son códigos equivalentes, luego si en uno de los casos hay un problema, en el otro, necesariamente, seguirá existiendo dicho problema

Comment: Explícame tu por que `total += (string_total[i] - '0')` es un problema, que no termino de entenderlo

Comment: Estoy completamente de acuerdo contigo, pero, de hecho cuando miré la pregunta he intenté darle una solución (qué es la que he colocado) y funcionó, luego estaba escribiendo la respuesta y me dí cuenta que era lo mismo que él tenía en su código, por eso te digo que intentes correr el código con eso que he hecho, y es por eso que te hago la pregunta ya que tú sabes más que yo (en el pasado he usado tus respuestas a otros usuarios para resolver mis dudas) para comprender porqué a mi me funciona mi respuesta y a él no.

Comment: Tienes que intentar entender qué sucede antes de proponer una solución. Encontrar el origen del problema probando al azar es como ganar la lotería. Además que es una práctica que te puede dar falsos positivos, como ha sido el caso. Poco después de tu respuesta puse la mía con la descripción del error... estabas cerca, ya que el error, efectivamente, está en el bucle, pero se trata de la variable `i` que no está inicializada